# What Bill Number is used if > 200 Government Bills are introduced in a session?

Tags: legislative-process, canada

[This website](https://sencanada.ca/en/sencaplus/how-why/whats-your-number-how-parliament-numbers-its-legislation/)    states:   Government bills in the Commons are numbered from 2-200, and private member's bills are numbered 201 and above. A similar scheme is used in the Senate.

What'd happen if more than 200 government bills were introduced in one session?

[image]

Comment: "Question is titled" is not a good clear body. I've written a question in the body.

Comment: Seriously: What is the record for a session? 50, 100?

Answer (score 5):

> What'd happen if more than 200 government bills were introduced in one
>   session?

The government would change the numbering system.